# Is there a database of protein sequences/structure along with their melting temperature?

Tags: database, public-databases

Such databases have been constructed for example in [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5626421/) or [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.compbiolchem.2009.10.002). But I can't find them anywhere online. Can someone point me to where I can find one available online?

Otherwise I'll have to write to these people and I don't know when/whether I'll get a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProTherm2 contains thermodynamic properties of proteins and mutants. https://www.iitm.ac.in/bioinfo/ProTherm2/ .

NAR Database issue advertises it as containing melting temperatures.

For the reference - found it with https://biokeanos.com/search?q=protein+%2Bmelting

Comment: Thanks! What amuses me is that back when I needed the database, we did contacted the authors of ProTherm for the data and used it. Seems like it's the only available database for this purpose, right now.